# How do I resolve NaN error in CoreGraphics with ios 'Charts' cocoapod?

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I'm getting the following error when I run my chart. How can I resolve this issue?

I'm currently using Daniel Gindi cocoapod 'Charts'.

When this error occurs the data doesn't draw on the graph.

"Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API and this value is being ignored. Please fix this problem."

Comment: Did you divide by 0 anywhere? Try using `print` statements to test.

Comment: no I'm adding three numbers and displaying them on a graph with time. Two of the numbers are from Healthkit. It only seems to happen on Sundays when there is no HealthKit input yet. After I get info from HealthKit it works normally again. The graph draws normally for the first few time and occasionally it just doesn't draw at all and I get the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is pretty straight forward. You are feeding a `NaN` value to core graphics. This is one of special values which is usually produced by undefined result such as division with zero. (Some other similar cases indicate infinite or negative infinite that are common when misusing trigonometrical functions).

In case of drawing a chart you can consider this very simple example which works sufficient:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    class ChartView: UIView {
        var values: [CGFloat] = []
        
        override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
            super.draw(rect)
            
            guard values.isEmpty == false else { return }
            
            let dx: CGFloat = bounds.width/CGFloat(values.count)
            let maxValue = values.max()!
            
            var x = dx*0.5 // Start position
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            var isFirstValue: Bool = true
            
            values.forEach { value in
                defer { x += dx }
                guard !isFirstValue else {
                    path.move(to: .init(x: x, y: (1.0 - value/maxValue)*bounds.height))
                    isFirstValue = false
                    return
                }
                path.addLine(to: .init(x: x, y: (1.0 - value/maxValue)*bounds.height))
            }
            
            path.stroke()
        }
    }
    
    let chartView = ChartView(frame: .init(x: 10.0, y: 100.0, width: 300.0, height: 200.0))
    chartView.backgroundColor = .gray
    chartView.values = [1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 12]
    view.addSubview(chartView)
}
```

you can create a new project and simply modify your autogenerated `viewDidLoad` to try it.

As soon as I do something silly such as `chartView.values = [0, 0]` the error will be printed such as

> Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API and this value is being ignored. Please fix this problem.

I am not sure what "Charts" cocoapod does but in my case I would say the bug is in tool to draw charts. However, you should be able to check if data that you are trying to draw actually makes sense.